# Could I get around a copyright by changing one small thing

Tags: intellectual-property

I am trying to make a computer program that simulates another computer. I want to simulate something called the Scott CPU (from [here](http://buthowdoitknow.com/)). Could I change a small thing about it and not have to ask for permission to use it?

Comment: It doesn't matter how much you change, you're still breaching copyright.

Answer (score 4):

The copyright holder has the rights in whatever he created. If you have created something new based on his idea, the law will generally not be interested; but if your expression is recognisably a copy with a few changes, he can prevent publication or demand royalties. If you are uncertain which side of the line you fall, you should ask a lawyer (or, more cheaply, write to the author and ask if he objects).

Comment: It might be helpful to mention the concept of "derivative works" explicitly. (+1 nonetheless)